# mouse down and moves down

Tags: c#, mouse

What's wrong with it?

```
    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        position_x = e.Location.X;
        position_y = e.Location.Y;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
     int position_x_next = e.Location.X;
     int position_y_next = e.Location.Y;

     if (position_x_next < position_x)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("it moved left");
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep track of the previous position of the mouse and the new position.

Create 2 new variables, `mouseIsDown` and `previousMouseX`.

In your `MouseDown` handler, set `mouseIsDown` to `true` and `previousMouseX` to `mouse.x` and set it to `false` in a `MouseUp` handler.

Then, add a `MouseMove` handler that checks if `previousMouseX` is greater than `mouse.x`.  If so, the mouse is moving left.  Make sure to update `previousMouseX` here as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should be checking the [`MouseEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.aspx) every time to see when the button is down and to capture the X and Y coordinates - you can tell it is moving left if the X coordinate is less than it was the last time.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple actually. Store the position it was in the last move event (it's in the `e` parameter). Then compare the current position with the last one. If its X coordinate is to the left it's moving left.

If you want to distinguish moving exactly left from moving diagonally left-up for instance, you should add a condition to check if the variation in the Y axis is small enough to account for user imprecision.

Answer (score 0):

The cheesy way:

Set a flag in the mouse down event IsMouseDown = true.
In the mouse move event check if IsMouseDown == true
In MouseUp set IsMouseDown = true

Answer (score 0):

What about the mouse move event and passing the X and Y cordinates

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove(VS.71).aspx

http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Event/MouseMovement.htm